# Printing SDK/API for Android/iPhone Application

Tags: android, iphone, mobile

I am using Titanium framework for building android and iPhone application. In one of my application I need to implement Print functionality. As there is no any functionality available for printing in Titanium framework, I need help to know Is there any open source or paid sdk/Api which allows Printing functionality in my application. I have referenced through google cloud print but It requires PC to be connected to printer and connector software of google. I want my app to allow printing to wifi printers and remote printers.

Any help regarding this appreciated.

Thanks,
Patrik

Answer (score 1):

Applications on iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch devices can print their contents to local printers. Printing was introduced as a system feature in iOS 4.2. Read more here - [Drawing and Printing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Printing/Printing.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need: 
www.isb-vietnam.com Or google for android printing framework.

Goodluck!